# converting NSDate from NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert date string "31 May 2016 17:04:14 GMT" to NSDate.

I have tried this:

```
NSString *stringDate = @"31 May 2016 17:04:14";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];
```

but date is always nil.

Any of you knows how can I fix this code to get the date in NSDate format?
NSDateFormatter

Comment: Read up on `hh` versus `HH`.

Comment: The format string is `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss`. Also, if you're dealing with international users, you might need to set `locale`, via `dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];` (see [Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1480/_index.html))